# Display property - Block behavior with inline width

Tags: html, css, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm trying to get the "block" display affect with the `AccordionPane` so that the panes align vertically with spacing. But using `display:block;` will stretch the header of the pane to fit the full available width.
Using `display:inline;` will get me the width behavior I desire, but then will stack the panes horizontally with no spacing.

For example, "Basic Info" is an unselected pane with `display: block;`. I want the width of the pane "Features" which has `display: inline;`

[image]

However, doing so results in the following:

[image]

Not only are the unselected panels smushed together horizontally, the tops are also cutoff from the Content pane.

I would like all of the panels to have width fit to the contents, but stack vertically with the clean spacing seen for `display: block;`. Is this possible?

Here is the aspx snippet:

```
<ajaxToolkit:Accordion
                     ClientIDMode="Static"
                     runat="server"
                     AutoSize="None"
                     Height="500"
                     ContentCssClass="accordion"
                     HeaderCssClass="accordionHeader"
                     HeaderSelectedCssClass="accordionHeaderSelected"
                     BorderStyle="None"
                     style="outline: none; vertical-align: top;"
                   >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get this behavior I needed to set it to `display: table;`

Comment: This being what I needed to set the display property to in order to get both the desired width and panel layout behavior makes it a complete answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but you'll need to float them `float:left; clear: both`, or set a fixed width for your items and use `display:block`.

Also use `display:inline-block` if you need the ability to set vertical margin.